# SQL Server : how to check reachability to server from a client machine

Tags: sql-server

I have a client process which talks to a DB server. When I have the client process pointed to a backup DB server, it does not come up. I am trying to verify whether the backup DB is reachable from this box. How can I verify? is ping alone sufficient or do I need something else as well?

Comment: The only (reliable) way to know if you'll be able to successfully connect to the server is to attempt to connect to the server. If, further, you want to know if you'll be able to accomplish task X, the only reliable way to know that is to attempt to accomplish task X. No amount of pre-checking of other details can prevent the fact that networks (and servers) are outside of your programs control and can change status at any time.

Comment: Maybe this tool? - http://www.sqlsecurity.com/downloads/sqlping.zip

Comment: can you post the exception details thrown by the process?
By analysing the exception details you can get the root cause.